# How to disable "IPHONE SOFTWARE UPDATE" notification on macOS Big Sur?

Tags: macos, software-update, system-settings

#### Problem

When I unlock my MacBook from the lock screen, macOS will push the "IPHONE SOFTWARE UPDATE" notification.

#### Question

How can I disable the "IPHONE SOFTWARE UPDATE" notification?

#### What I try

Open **System Preference** > **Notifications** Panel, find any application suspected. I think notification is Finder pushed (I double click notification finder display).

---

I don't want to disable macOS update, I just want to disable "IPHONE SOFTWARE UPDATE"

[image: Screenshot of multiple iPhone Software Update notifications]

Comment: I've never know it be quite so aggressive… but you could always run the update, which is now 2 months old...

Comment: @Tetsujin I can't update my iPhone, because I need do some research work on my iPhone with current iOS version :[

Comment: I have the same problem.